# EPiServer 9 - Add block to new page programmatically

Tags: block, episerver, episerver-9

I have found some suggestions on how to add a block to a page, but can't get it to work the way I want, so perhaps someone can help out.
What I want to do is to have a scheduled job that reads through a file, creating new pages with a certain pagetype and in the new page adding some blocks to a content property. The blocks fields will be updated with data from the file that is read.

I have the following code in the scheduled job, but it fails at

```
repo.Save((IContent) newBlock, SaveAction.Publish);
```

giving the error

> The page name must contain at least one visible character.

This is my code:

```
public override string Execute() 
{
    //Call OnStatusChanged to periodically notify progress of job for manually started jobs
    OnStatusChanged(String.Format("Starting execution of {0}", this.GetType()));

    //Create Person page                      
    PageReference parent = PageReference.StartPage;

    //IContentRepository contentRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
    //IContentTypeRepository contentTypeRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentTypeRepository>();

    //var repository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
    //var slaegtPage = repository.GetDefault<SlaegtPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);

    IContentRepository contentRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
    IContentTypeRepository contentTypeRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentTypeRepository>();

    SlaegtPage slaegtPage = contentRepository.GetDefault<SlaegtPage>(parent, contentTypeRepository.Load("SlaegtPage").ID);

    if (slaegtPage.MainContentArea == null) {
        slaegtPage.MainContentArea = new ContentArea();
    }            

    slaegtPage.PageName = "001 Kim";

    //Create block
    var repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

    var newBlock = repo.GetDefault<SlaegtPersonBlock1>(ContentReference.GlobalBlockFolder);

    newBlock.PersonId = "001";
    newBlock.PersonName = "Kim";
    newBlock.PersonBirthdate = "01 jan 1901";           

    repo.Save((IContent) newBlock, SaveAction.Publish);

    //Add block
    slaegtPage.MainContentArea.Items.Add(new ContentAreaItem
        {
            ContentLink = ((IContent) newBlock).ContentLink
        });

    slaegtPage.URLSegment = UrlSegment.CreateUrlSegment(slaegtPage);

    contentRepository.Save(slaegtPage, EPiServer.DataAccess.SaveAction.Publish);

    _stopSignaled = true;

    //For long running jobs periodically check if stop is signaled and if so stop execution
    if (_stopSignaled) {
        return "Stop of job was called";
    }

    return "Change to message that describes outcome of execution";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the Name by

```
((IContent) newBlock).Name = "MyName";
```

Comment: @kilarsen if an answer solved your problem, please mark it as an answer and also vote up for it